# What is a chai chai kick?

Tags: genshiken

Genshiken Nidaime, Episode 5, 19:34

Chai... Chai Kick! where did this come from?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably from [History's Strongest Disciple Kenichi](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=6864). As the Muay Thai boxer, Apachai Hopachai, one of Kenichi's teachers, has a special technique called the [Chai Kick](http://kenichi.wikia.com/wiki/Chai_Kick).

[image]